# How to convert tf.feature_column into a tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, embeddings

I'd like to get an average embedding to use as an input.

Without feature_column, it can be done in this way
(from [Tensorflow: how to look up and average a different amount of embedding vectors per training instance, with multiple training instances per minibatch?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38887/tensorflow-how-to-look-up-and-average-a-different-amount-of-embedding-vectors-p))

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    embedding = tf.placeholder(shape=[10,3], dtype=tf.float32)
    user = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32)
    selected = tf.gather(embedding, user)
    non_zero_count =  tf.cast(tf.count_nonzero(user, axis=1), tf.float32)
    embedding_sum = tf.reduce_sum(selected, axis=1) 
    average = embedding_sum / tf.expand_dims(non_zero_count, axis=1)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        embedding_ = np.concatenate([np.zeros((1,3)),np.random.randn(9,3)], axis=0)
        user_ = [[3,5,7,0], [1,2,0,0]]
        print(sess.run(average, feed_dict={embedding:embedding_, user:user_}))
        print(np.sum([embedding_[i] for i in user_], axis=1) / np.atleast_2d(np.count_nonzero(user_, axis=1)).T)
```

If I could convert feature_column into a tensor, I could do similar thing, but don't know how to convert

```
     user_fc = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
         'user', [3,5,7,1,2,0])                                                                                                                                  
     user_embedding_column = feature_column.embedding_column(user, dimension=3)
     embedding = user_embedding.to_tensor() # if I can do this,  I could replace the embedding in the code above with this.
```